# Negative vote retaliation

Tags: support, downvotes

I think someone I was arguing with in an answer I gave today may have retaliated against my downvote by finding another question I asked over a year ago and downvoting it. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: If it was just one downvote, you'll just have to move on. You cannot even be sure it was the same user; you'd be surprised how often coincidences happen. If someone serial-voted (multiple downvotes *or* upvotes on one person's posts) then that'll be taken care of automatically.

Comment: I'm 95% sure, I'm not a very active user, so theres often no change in my reputation for weeks. That downvoted question was the first question I asked on the site and hasn't received any votes in over a year... then I answer a question from today and argue with someone for a bit, and bam.
I'll get over it no prob, it just felt like abuse so I figured I'd ask about it. Thanks.

Comment: I once had someone go to alot of my answers and if the answers didn't have a link to the docs for reference, he would downvote for not referencing the docs...

Comment: Technical disagreement is settled here in answers.  Make your case convincing enough and your answer will automatically rise to the top.  Arguing about it in comments doesn't accomplish anything but ticking people off, what happens next tends to be predictable.  Yes, do delete that comment, that does nothing but create a long-term grudge.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's nothing that can be done.  Voting is anonymous, so we don't even know who did it.

There's a nightly voter fraud detection script that will remove votes that demonstrate a pattern of voter fraud, but that won't detect this.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov shhh... don't tell him how you voted... its a secret!